# Assembly code that receives a value as INPUT, outputs a multiple of 3 less than that value, and outputs the sum of the multiples

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

## I'm inputting assembly code like the title in the SASM program, and it works fine until the output of multiples of 3, but the sum of them is not output, so I'm holding on for 10 hours. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me where the hell I went wrong. The line that outputs the sum of the multiples starts at line 42.

```
%include "io64.inc"

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov rbp,rsp
    PRINT_STRING msg_input
    GET_DEC 2,data_max
    NEWLINE
    
    mov [data_size],word 0
    mov edx, 1 
L1: 
    mov bl,3
    mov ax,dx
    div bl
    cmp ah,0
    jne L_next
    mov eax,0
    mov ax,[data_size]
    mov [data + eax*2], dx
    inc eax
    mov [data_size],ax
L_next:
    inc edx
    cmp dx,[data_max]
    jle L1
    
    PRINT_STRING msg_count
    PRINT_DEC 2,[data_size]
    NEWLINE
    mov eax,0
L_print:
    PRINT_DEC 2,[data + eax*2]
    NEWLINE
    inc eax
    cmp ax,word [data_size]
    jl L_print
    ;;;;
L_SET:
    mov [total],word 0
    mov eax,0
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,[data_size]
L_BODY:
    add ebx,[data + eax*2]
    inc eax
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx,0
    jg L_BODY
    mov [total],ebx
    PRINT_STRING msg_total
    PRINT_DEC 2,[total]
      
    xor rax,rax
    ret
    
section .data
    msg_input db "# input max number:",0x00
    msg_count db "# number count:",0x00
    msg_total db "# total:",0x00
    
section .bss
    data_max resw 1
    data_size resw 1
    data resw 100
    total resw 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Bvh.png)

If you put 13 in INPUT, the sum should be 30, but when you check the result, the sum doesn't come out. It just comes out 3,6,9,12.

Even though I've been holding onto the code for nearly 10 hours, I don't know what to do because I'm a beginner learning assembly language for the first time.

Comment: Single-step your code with a debugger so you can look at values in registers.  Also, rounding down to a multiple of 3 doesn't need a loop: `x = (x/3)*3` with truncating integer division.  Or if you're counting up, use a loop like `for(int i=3 ; i<x ; i+=3)`.  No division or multiplication required.

Comment: Also, 64-bit code should use 64-bit addressing, like `mov [data + rax*2], dx`.  `data_size` should be an assemble-time EQU constant like `data_size equ 100` so you can `mov eax, data_size`, but when you do want to do a zero-extending load, it's `movzx eax, word [data_size]`.  Or wait, your program starts by overwriting the `dw 100` with a constant `0`?  That's weird.  Just use a register to keep track of size.  x86-64 has 15 registers other than the stack pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> data_size resw 1
> data resw 100
> total resw 1
> ```

Because you defined *total* to be a **word**, you should never write a **dword** value to it. So you should change `mov [total],ebx` into `mov [total], bx`.
Because *total* is the last variable on the list, this error didn't matter so much.

However, you also have `mov ecx,[data_size]` that reads a **full dword** from a variable that was defined as a **mere word** and that will harm the program. It so happens that the word that follows *data_size* got filled with the value **3** (first number on the list). Therefore ECX will receive a very big number 00030004h (196612), making the loop run for much too long and making the loop addressing memory far beyond the .bss section!

To make matters even worse, there's also `add ebx,[data + eax*2]` that reads a **dword** from an array that just contains a number of **words**.

### Try next suggestion

I kept the word-sized approach, but in this 32-bit (or is it 64-bit because I see `mov rbp,rsp`) program, you should consider using dwords for the lot: dword variables and dword operations.

```
L_SET:
    xor   eax, eax
    xor   ebx, ebx
    movzx ecx, word [data_size]
L_BODY:
    add   bx, [data + eax*2]
    inc   eax
    dec   ecx
    jnz   L_BODY
    mov   [total], bx
```

Tip: You don't need any divisions by 3 to create a list of multiples of 3. Just a simple loop where you add 3 to the previous value for as long as the new value remains less than the limit.

Comment: It's definitely 64-bit code, `mov rbp, rsp` won't assemble otherwise.  So you want `[data + rax*2]` after zeroing RAX with `xor eax,eax`.  Dword operand-size is still totally normal for 64-bit code, unlike word, and sign-extends for free.